# ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Core Can't Load Proper Sqlite DLL

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, ormlite-servicestack

I'll keep this short and sweet...

OS:  Windows 7 x64 Latest Updates
IDE: Visual Studio 2017 15.2
Framework: .Net Core 1.1 / Standard 1.3

Steps to reproduce:

1) File -> New Project (.Net Core Console App)
2) Created a simple Customer Poco
3) Install-Package ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Core (ver is 1.0.42)
4) Bring in namespaces for Customer Poco
5) var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("mypath\test.sqlite", SqliteDialect.Provider, false);
6) Using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())...

At this point I get:

System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

So basically I literally file newed everything up, installed the appropriate package and it's dependencies and did the most basic create of a simple table and I get this error straight away.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: @mythz Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Open Nuget package manager and install Microsoft.Data.Sqlite

ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Core doesn't bring Sqlite along with it, you must install it first.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't help unfortunately.  This was more than a month ago when I asked and I've gotten EF to work just fine since.  Thanks for trying though Brian.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding Microsoft.Data.Sqlite Version=1.1.1 instead of the latest? I had the same issues on OSX and you have the option to select an older version of the sqlite package. That helped me.

Comment: I ended up just using EF instead of ServiceStack and it's working well for me now.  Thanks for posting those since this could help others.